# HTML - bxslider Implementation

Tags: html, image, slider, gallery, bxslider

I am implementing an image slider (bxslider) into my website.  I have followed the setup instructions exactly from http://bxslider.com/ with no luck.  Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

    <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
    <script src="bxslider/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
    <link href="bxslider/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The extracted bxslider files are in the root directory of the website in a folder called "bxslider".

Comment: I dont see any problem with your code. I have tried this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/4jFZe/). Are your Bxslider JS files properly referenced?

Comment: I have the bxSlider files in a folder called "bxslider" in the root of my server.  Am I referencing them correctly in my code?

Comment: Hopefully. Its hard to determine. Check the console and see if they are being loaded by the browser.

Comment: Code looks fine. Did you get it working?

Comment: Yeah I had one of the references wrong.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your solution you did not refer the source file of bxslider. and for saved jquery documents

for example you missed http: in this script

for more information see this link

http://www.knowledgewalls.com/b.gopalakrishnan92/books/jquery-examples/bx-photo-slider-example-program